# Passing Data Between Fragments Using Safe Args

Tags: android, gradle, android-fragments, android-safe-args

I'm trying to implement data transfer between fragments using Safe Args, but I'm stuck at the moment of setting Gradle.

Project Gradle looks like this

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.1.3' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
}



task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module Gradle is like this

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.main_fragmentargs"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    buildFeatures{
        viewBinding true
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.0"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.0"

}
```

Wherever I enter this line, Gradle starts to swear.

apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"

Similar story with

def nav_version = "2.3.3"

classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"

Please tell me how to connect it.

Comment: Wherever I enter this line, Gradle starts to swear.
Can you pls elaborate?

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/XFNoT
Maybe I put it in the wrong place? But I tried different options.

Comment: What was the issue. You haven't mentioned your issue. Share your compile logs

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the plugin to your plugin closure, like described in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data#Safe-args).

Add this to your top level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }    
    dependencies {
        def nav_version = "2.5.0"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$nav_version"
    }
}
...
```

and this to your app modules build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin'
}
...
```

Also make sure that `android.useAndroidX=true` is set in your gradle.properties files.